# Making WebApp which can CRUD Form and Controller on the fly (Java)

Tags: java, web-applications, frameworks, on-the-fly

Currently I want to replace my old web-app

my old web-app is outdated framework using ZK API that no longer supported by them

My web-app can do this on its own website app

1. Can design a form (GUI) for a specific menu. such as insert a layout, label, textfield, datebox, listbox, etc
2. Can make a script code for point 1 GUI so that GUI have an action (like a controller), such acc textbox validation, button action, CRUD action, etc

All those point is like plug and play, save the code and on the fly running without compile and restart web app in the web app server.

My question is which framework that support my old web app feature so i can make a new one like this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using JHipster for my fast CRUD projects. You can create projects with ready database and simple dashboard in a few minutes from CLI, by the help of its entegration with Yeoman and AngularJS. It uses Spring Boot at server-side. You can find more detail at https://jhipster.github.io/